# Looking open source project to parallelise

Tags: c#, java, open-source, parallel-processing

For an assignment I need to parallelise a project, and document on my work and outcomes.  So, Im looking for an ideal open-source C# or Java project that would require about 60hrs of work, (so reasonably small - sorry for the generalisation, not sure how to put it into perspective, considering Im still studying) and fairly cpu intensive.
Have looked through Source forge and nothing struck me.  Short of downloading and compiling 10 or so projects and running them through a profiler, can anyone make a suggestion as to how I could go about finding one? Or even if you know of one?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a Java project I will suggest Map-Reduce and Hadoop as frameworks of choice. I work in image processing and the problems there are trivially parallel as noted by Brian. The other area is in array based simulations, e.g. n-body models. A quick check gives me [this](http://www.drugphish.ch/~ratz/java/) GPL'ed Java Source - it looks fairly small. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to locate an image processing library or application. Several of the filters/conversions can be parallelized without too much fuss.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any projects myself, but your post made me think of the programs that do long computations like Seti@Home and that other one I cannot remember the name of which does the human genome decoding.

Perhaps something along those lines.

Comment: Unfortunately none are C#/Java

Answer (score 0):

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/ pretty sure it runs on multiple cores though...